# データ全体での正規化

Tags: python

12*140のデータ(data.csv)がありグラフに示すと上の画像のようになりました．[image: data.csvのグラフ]
このデータに正規化を施し最大値がそろってしまっていることなどに注目すると12個のデータごとに正規化を施すようになってしまっていると思います．これをデータ全体で正規化してある程度元の山の形を保ったままのグラフを再現したいです．ご教授お願いします．[image: 正規化したグラフ]
下にコード示しています．（元データが複雑なため読み込むコードは省略していますがdataは12×140のデータを示しています．）

```
#元のグラフ
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

ch = np.array(range(1,13))
plt.plot(ch,data[0:12], linestyle='None',marker='o')

#正規化
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing impor24，t MinMaxScaler
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler([0,1])
scaler.fit(data) #dataは12*140のデータ
data_del_mms = scaler.transform(data)
data_del_mms_t=data_del_mms.T
plt.plot(ch,data_del_mms[0:12], linestyle='None',marker='o')
```

Comment: この記事 [Scikit-learnでデータのスケール変換（前処理）する](https://helve-python.hatenablog.jp/entry/scikitlearn-scale-conversion) を参考にやり方を調整してみるとか？

Comment: 素朴な感想ですが、連続していた（点の間隔が

Comment: 上の画像では、ほぼ均一に並んでいた点が、正規化で分散してしまい、下の画像のX＝７辺りのデータは、[0,1]の区間にFITするはずが[0.9, 1.0]ぐらいのところに集まっているように見えます。（まぁ、[0.9, 1.0]の区間は、[0,1]の区間の中なんですが）
これで正しく正規化されているのですか？